# Leibniz Notation for Derivative Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Does the following agree with proper notation?  I think my understanding is incorrect.

$$
y = f(x)
$$

Without an argument ($x$ is left undefined?):
$$
\frac {dy}{dx} = f' = \lim_{h \to 0} {\frac {f(h+x) - f(x)}{(h+x) -x}} 
$$
With an argument:
$$
\frac {dy}{dx}(x)=\frac {dy}{dx} \Big|_{x} = f'(x) 
= \lim_{h \to 0} {\frac {f(h+x) - f(x)}{(h+x) -x}} 
$$
or optionally, with argument using  new symbol to reduce confusion:

$$
\frac {dy}{dx}(a)=\frac {dy}{dx} \Big|_{a} = f'(a) 
= \lim_{h \to 0} {\frac {f(h+a) - f(a)}{(h+a) -a}} 
$$

Finally, I think the point of differentiation can be a variable vs argument as follows:
$$
x=a,\frac {dy}{dx}= f'(a) 
= \lim_{h \to 0} {\frac {f(h+a) - f(a)}{(h+a) -a}} 
$$

My original questions are posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038748/chain-rule-in-leibniz-and-lagrange-notation-questions/4038870#4038870) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040329/leibniz-question-on-notation-specifically-using-with-vertical-point-bars).

Comment: looks ok. But I prefer, for clarity: $
\frac {dy}{dx}(\xi)=\frac {dy}{dx} \Big|_{\xi} = f'(\xi) $. Or even $\frac {dy}{dx} \Big|_{x=\xi}$.

Comment: Everything's fine, except the third Leibniz notation with the $\mid$. You can think of this line as if it's the line at the end from integrals where you have to plug the boundaries in. In this case $x$ is not a boundarie or a value at some point, it's the function variable. Also you may simplify $(x+h)-x$.

Comment: @311411 I thought of that earlier to eliminate confusion between $dx$ and $x$.  If these are two distinct objects then there should be no confusion I think.  Should there be a difference equation on the RHS of $f'$ equality?

Comment: @vitamind can you clarify?  I have seen $\frac {dy}{dx}(x)=\frac {dy}{dx} \Big|_{x}$ defined as such from at least one author.  My understanding is the $ \Big|_{x}$ represents substitution of the bar $x$ for the values of $x$ in the difference quotient or similarly substitution of $x$ into $f'(x)$.  For $(x + h) - x$, I left it for understanding.

Comment: I have never seen the Leibniz notation with a bar in one "serious" paper. I would not say it's wrong it's just very uncomfortable to write and can cause confusion.

Comment: I had a comment that $\frac {dy}{dx} \ne f'$ and that $\frac {dy}{dx} = f'(x)$.  I suspect $x=a, \frac {dy}{dx} = f'(a)$ but am not exactly sure.  Does anyone know when $f'$ should be distinguished as having the argument applied as $f'(x)$?